# Backups tool does not show the hard drive

Tags: partitioning, mount, backup, external-hdd

I am trying to back up my Ubuntu partition using the `Backups` app to an external USB hard drive. I have formatted the drive (NTFS) and mounted it to `/media`. I can access the mounted drive and write and read to and from it using the file  browser and from terminal. However, it doesn't show up and offer the disk as a possible location to backup to in the `Backups` app. Any suggestions?

Comment: See the answer given by @srs5694 on this link: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1571194

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't backup the system partition with `deja-dup` (the name of the backup tool), this tool can be used for backing up your personal stuff. When you want to backup the Ubuntu system partition, you can use [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/). Download the ISO file and create a bootable media from it.
Boot from the CD/DVD/USB media you created - here you see how to perform everything :

[Clonezilla : How to backup (operating system) partitions](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/13-GCZyxH51pWD-aMzmD-QNpDr7U28ZqTmEB-Iy3wizM/edit?usp=sharing)

[Clonezilla : How to restore (operating system) partitions](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1mSc1BAJBIQMbKKzI2OjG9tWEt7p7GeGY50InYgWzgVQ/edit?usp=sharing)